# Gps android - getting Latitude and Longitude

Tags: java, android, geolocation

Can you help me with that.. application started to crash when I added the geocoder to get the name of the city by using latitude and longitude..

```
    double latitude, longitude;
    private TextView lala;

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
    lala = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());   
    List<Address> myList = null;
    try {
        myList = myLocation.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    lala.setText((CharSequence) myList);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lm.getLastKnownLocation` can return null, and then tou try to `getLongitude()` you'll get `NullPointerException`

Also `lala.setText((CharSequence) myList);` can do the same (throw Exception) cause' myList can be null here (if `Geocoder` is failed).

**EDIT**
To deal with exception in Geocoder consider the following checklist

1. Make sure your latitude and longitude are not null
2. Make sure what -90 <= latitude <= 90 and -180 <= longitude <= 180
3. Make sure you are having available network connection

**EDIT2**
Improved code

```
private TextView lala;

LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if(location != null) {
    showMyAddress(location);
}

final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        showMyAddress(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
lala = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);



// Also declare a private method

private void showMyAddress(Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());   
    List<Address> myList;
    try {
        myList = myLocation.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if(myList.size() == 1) {
            lala.setText(myList.get(0).toString());             
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right.. but can You tell me what to do to make Geocoder not to fail.. Sorry, I'm beginner in android and java..

Comment: okey..
Now i have Latitude: 59.412.. and Longitude: 24.689..
And my network connection working fine..
Maybe there is something wrong with my code

Comment: Yes, i've found one more error - you are casting List<Address> to CharSequence which is can't be done. See my second edit.

Comment: Ok...You're my savior.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
int la = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
int lo = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
```